# Send Email from Alias Address using SMTP

Tags: c#, smtp

This question has been asked so many times but I am still struggling to find a working solution.

Please consider the below code:

```
    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("outlook.office365.com");
    MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage();
    msgMail.From = new MailAddress("validUser@domain.com", "displayName@aliasDomain.com");
    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("validUser@domain.com", "password");
    mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    MailAddress sendMailTo = new MailAddress("someValidUser@someValidDomain.com", "Mark Twain")
    msgMail.To.Add(sendMailTo);
    msgMail.Subject = "Test Subject";

    msgMail.Body = "Email content";
    msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    mailClient.Send(msgMail);
    msgMail.Dispose();
```

When `someValidUser` - the recipient - receives the email, I want it to show the display name : `displayName@aliasDomain.com` as opposed to the username registered to the `validUser@domain.com` account.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the display name to the headers of the message:

```
msgMail.Headers.Add("Sender", "displayName@aliasDomain.com");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Could this be related to your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209163/send-an-email-using-smtp-and-control-sender-address?rq=1

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I want to achieve but I am not using Gmail but Outlook's SMTP server.. same applies?

Answer (score 1):

If you reset the from address in the MailMessage object you should be able to send from the alias email address. See below for the full code.

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("root@bobloblaw.com", "Root");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("plaintiff@gmail.com", "Plaintiff");
string fromPassword = "password";
string subject = "Your Lawsuit";
string body = "I regret to inform you...";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587, 
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
    Timeout = 20000
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress) 
    {
        Subject = subject, 
        Body = body, 
        From = new MailAddress("bob@bobloblaw.com", "Bob Lob") 
    })
{ 
    smtp.Send(message); 
}
```

Comment: @GekaP Could you share any more information? I think it depends on your smtp server. For instance, the method above works for me without issue with gmail.

Comment: I use Office 365 mail service. Their smtp server does not care which DisplayName you provide in MailMessage class - it is always overwritten by Display Name which is configured on your 365 mail account. I tried tons of different things, but unfortunately, nothing can be done with this. I think about moving to another mail service which supports this option.

Answer (score 0):

This can work if you simply add an Alias to the Office 365 mailbox. Then use the Alias in the From field and the original username+password for the Credentials.

The recipients will see the name+alias you specify in the From field and not the username for the account. Just tried this with PowerShell Send-MailMessage as well as C#.