# How to send email from Contact us form Website to Gmail Account

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm new to Asp.Net and created a "Contact us" form which has four text boxes namely: "Name", "Contact Number", "Email" and "Message" that has a Submit button below.

My problem is after sending a message to the specific gmail address/account, I'm getting response to my email address only in Gmail inbox (that is, in the inbox it says from: **myemail@gmail.com** to:**myemail@gmail.com**) instead of showing the text taken from `txtemail.Text` text box.

**Email.aspx**

```asp
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
            <legend>Contact Us Form</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Conatct Number
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontact" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Email
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Message
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtmessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Email.aspx.cs**

```c#
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        //Sender e-mail address.
        
        //Recipient e-mail address.
        Msg.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");// this email address will receives
        Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtemail.Text);
        //Meaages Subject
        Msg.Subject = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Name :" + txtname.Text + "\r\n");
        sb.Append("Contact:" + txtcontact.Text + "\r\n");
        sb.Append("Email:" + txtemail.Text + "\r\n");
        sb.Append("Message:" + txtmessage.Text + "\r\n");

        Msg.Body = sb.ToString();
        // SMTP server IP.
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(Msg);
        //Mail Message
        Response.Write("<Script>alert('Thanks for contact us,our team will be contact you as soon as possible')</Script>");
        // Clear the textbox values
        txtname.Text = "";
        txtcontact.Text = "";
        txtemail.Text = "";
        txtmessage.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate. Please see [Send an email using SMTP and control sender address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209163/send-an-email-using-smtp-and-control-sender-address)

Comment: @derloopkat I followed all the steps but problem is i am receiving with the same email address in "From" and "To" in gmail inbox. Is it problem in my code?

Comment: Just make sure the `from` email account exists at the mail server you're using to send your messages.